# Can I manually extract a h.264 bitstream from an MP4 with a simple algorithm

Tags: h.264, mp4

I know there are several tools like MP4Box to extract a bitstream, but is the bitstream linear enough to be extracted from an MP4 file manually? Let's say any iPhone or Windows Phone usual MP4/AVC.

Is this a waste of time, or I could easily extract an intact .264 track from an MP4 with a simple loop algorithm?

Comment: If you expect this to work with any given MP4 file, then no you cannot do it. Some video only files might have H.264 payload data easily extractable under certain assumptions made for file structure - yes you can do the trick with these files (actually it might be as simple as just removing header there).

Comment: Ok. I guess I'll see it directly in the first step, which is to compare an h.264 bitstream extracted with ffmpeg with the original phone video. But in that case, I think the MP4a track is mixed with the video, so cleaning it quickly will be hard. Checking!

Comment: Define Simple.

It's not very complicated to read the MOOV box, read the the track ID of the h264 stream, and then read all the moof box payloads with the correct track ID. Are you looking for something simpler?